# can we use aspose api for identify section no. with page no. in doc file in java

Tags: java, doc, sections, aspose.words

i want to identify sections in a doc file with page no through aspose java api.

if i am creating doc file with aspose api and trying to identify section no with page no its giving but when i am  browsing any existing file its not giving in proper manner

```
NodeCollection nodes = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.ANY, true);
for (Node node : (Iterable<Node>) nodes) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("->  NodeType.{0}:", node.getNodeType()));
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("\tStarts on page {0}, ends on page {1}, spanning {2} pages.", layoutCollector.getStartPageIndex(node), layoutCollector.getEndPageIndex(node), layoutCollector.getNumPagesSpanned(node)));
}

// We can iterate over the layout entities using a LayoutEnumerator
LayoutEnumerator layoutEnumerator = new LayoutEnumerator(doc);
Assert.assertEquals(LayoutEntityType.PAGE, layoutEnumerator.getType());

// The LayoutEnumerator can traverse the collection of layout entities like a tree
// We can also point it to any node's corresponding layout entity like this
layoutEnumerator.setCurrent(layoutCollector.getEntity(doc.getChild(NodeType.PARAGRAPH, 1, true)));
Assert.assertEquals(LayoutEntityType.SPAN, layoutEnumerator.getType());
Assert.assertEquals("¶", layoutEnumerator.getText());
```

i expect output in separate section available on separate page

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need new section start on new page, then LayoutEnumerator is not required at all. You have several options to start contend from new page.

1. Page break
   https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/breaktype#PAGE_BREAK
2. Section break New Page
   https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/breaktype#SECTION_BREAK_NEW_PAGE
3. PageBreakBefore property of paragraph 
   https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/paragraphformat#PageBreakBefore

If for example each section (logical section, not section inserted by section break) starts with heading paragraph, then you can simply change the corresponding styles’s ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore property and every paragraph with this style applied will start from new page.

Hope this helps.